# How to get list page mode using cookies in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to know that which listing mode is running i.e. grid or list using cookie in magento. I hope magento already setting up cookies for list mode :)

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code taken from *app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php:523* should get you something like this:

```php
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getDisplayMode()
```

And in the exact same file, above line 517:

```php
if ($mode == $defaultMode) {
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsDisplayMode();
}
```

So, that means that, if you have nothing from the code `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getDisplayMode()`, you are in the default mode (the one configured as the default in your admin or in your template.)

To understand the full logic please have a look at `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getDisplayMode()`

And depending on where you are trying to do that you can also try

```php
$this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
```

As in *app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php:130*

Comment: Hi Enoit, Thanks for your answer :)

But I just tried this & not working :( I mean it is not returning anything. So I wrote how to get it from cookies. I am sure magento may be storing mode value in cookies :)

Any Idea?

Comment: A session in Magento is stored as a cookie, so yes, the above line of code should return you the value in the cookie IF it is set. Otherwise that means it is not set in the cookie.

Comment: Humm Humm ok Enoit :)

Now the thing is should I include or Mage or app something like that? Can you please give syntax for that? I would like to add it & then want to try this statement.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Enoit, I just got one solution i.e. working :)

Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager)->getCurrentMode();

But your answer is worth & quite true :)

Thanks again Enoit :)